# calling 2 input values from a method

Tags: c#, oop

I have been trying to work this concept out for days. I have a console program with 3 classes :

1) Main program
2) Create Login screen
3) Actual Login screen

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
       //Instantiate Main Menu
        Menu myMenu = new Menu();
        myMenu.mainMenu();

        //testing global values
        Login myLogin = new Login();
        Console.Write("The new Login is ");
        Console.WriteLine(myLogin.newLogin);

        //Pause
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Menu
{         
    public void mainMenu()
    {          
        // [create menu that prints choices on the screen]
        start:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("PLEASE CHOOSE AN OPTION");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("[1] LOGIN \n[2] CREATE LOGIN");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("> ");

        string menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        // [switch/case for Main Menu]
        switch (menuChoice) 
        {
            case "1":
                Console.WriteLine("You chose 1");
                break;
            case "2":                    
                // [instantiate createLogin]
                Login myLogin = new Login();                        
                myLogin.createLogin(); 
                Console.WriteLine(myLogin.newLogin);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("INVALID OPTION... TRY AGAIN.");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                goto start;

        }
}

class Login
{
    // [empty containers for newLogin & newPass]
    public string newLogin { get; set; }
    public string newPass { get; set; }

    public void createLogin()
    {
        // [display new login screen & assign newLogin & newPass]
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("CREATE NEW LOGIN");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("LOGIN: ");
        newLogin = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("PASSWORD: ");            
        newPass = Console.ReadLine();

        // [instantiate & return to main menu]
        Menu myMenu = new Menu();
        myMenu.mainMenu();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to output the code from main program the value is null. Do I have the wrong structure here? I dont really need to store more than one login and pass (for now) so an array is not needed at this point, but im sure ill learn that down the road. I am self learning so I am trying to keep things as simple as I can until I nail the concept.

I want to store the newLogin and newPass and print the values in main. Please help.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Sorry what is null? It is not clear from your question. What is your error/what doesn't work?

Comment: Im trying to query the value of newLogin & newPass and output the value to main.

Comment: Then why do you recreate myMenu in the create login method? Why do you need two copies of it?

Comment: sorry, I copied and pasted before i commented those lines out. That was just to loop back to the main menu. They are commented out and I have a blank (what i mean by null) value for newLogin when called in main.

Comment: Now that im looking at it, I guess that code should be outside the method. Another nice catch. thanks.  edit: maybe it cant, because it is part of the method to return.. lol

Comment: ah ok. makes more sense!

Comment: I found an answer. It may not be the best, but it works. Once I corrected the Query/Write problem (listed above) I started thinking more about instances and realized that BY CREATING THE NEW INSTANCE I AM IN FACT CLEARING THE DATA. Sorry for the caps but my intent is to help some other self learner.

Ok so in theory I want to keep the createLogin method once its called in the case. How do I keep it? I made the createLogin, newLogin, and newPass classes static so that the value can be assigned and the class can then be called from main. I didnt have enough rep to answer my own question... lol

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
 .....
 case "2":                    
   // [instantiate createLogin]
   Login myLogin = new Login();
   Console.WriteLine(myLogin.newLogin);  //WRITE TO CONSOLE
   myLogin.createLogin();                // QUERY AFTER WRITE
 ......
```

You *first* write an emtpy login, and after only query for it. So it's "normal" that you don't see any login information on the scree, as it printed *before* it was intitialized and after never printed again.

To resolve this, just invert function calls:

```
 .....
 case "2":                    
   // [instantiate createLogin]
   Login myLogin = new Login();       
   myLogin.createLogin();                // QUERY 
   Console.WriteLine(myLogin.newLogin);  //WRITE TO CONSOLE
 ...
```

**EDIT**

If you want to operate over `Login`, one of possible solutions is:

```
class Menu
{
    private Login _login = new Login(); // EVERYWHERE IN MENU USE THIS FIELD, THE SAME INSTANCE

.....
 case "2":                    
   // [instantiate createLogin]
   //Login myLogin = new Login();        NO MORE NEW INSTANCE BUT USE ALREADY AVAILABLE ONE
   _login.createLogin();                // QUERY 
   Console.WriteLine(_login .newLogin);  //WRITE TO CONSOLE
 ...

}
```

Comment: you are correct. nice catch, thank you. That will return the string value once created (only inside the case). My question is can I query newLogin for the values only? I am trying to pass them to main. I know that createLogin is marked as void, but I thought because I assigned the set;get; at the beginning of the class I could query just the values. thanks for all your help again.

Comment: At this point you can add `Login` property in your `Menu` class, and work with that. Do not more create a `new` Login but use a property of Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's showing up as null in Main()? You're also printing `myLogin.newLogin` in your Menu switch/case. When you print it in your Menu, you're printing it before calling myLogin.createLogin() so it should be null, but by the time it gets back to Main() it should be set correctly.

Comment: The question still exists. I need to pass the values of newLogin & newPass over to main.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. It may not be the best, but it works. Once I corrected the Query/Write problem (listed above) I started thinking more about instances and realized that BY CREATING THE NEW INSTANCE I AM IN FACT CLEARING THE DATA. Sorry for the caps but my intent is to help some other self learner.

Ok so in theory I want to keep the createLogin method once its called in the case. How do I keep it? I made the createLogin, newLogin, and newPass classes static so that the value can be assigned and the class can then be called from main. By calling it without instantiating it, it keeps the value assigned.

```
class Login
    {
    // [empty containers for newLogin & newPass]
    public static string newLogin { get; set; }
    public static string newPass { get; set; }

public static void createLogin()
{           
    // [display new login screen & assign values]
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("CREATE NEW LOGIN");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("LOGIN: ");
    newLogin = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("PASSWORD: ");            
    newPass = Console.ReadLine();

    // [instantiate & return to main menu]
    //Menu myMenu = new Menu();
    //myMenu.mainMenu();
}
```

and in main:

```
//testing global values            
            Console.Write("The new Login is ");                  
            Console.WriteLine(Login.newLogin);
```

This works, thanks everyone for contributing. It was with others comments that I was able to figure this one out. Hope my solution is clear for someone else. Peace.